# Have VIM show R function arguments

Tags: r, vim, macvim

The Mac R-Gui has a nice feature where when you start typing a function, the bottom status bar  tells you what arguments the function takes. For example, see the following image, when I type traceback:

[image]

I love this feature, but would really like it if I could use Vim to get similar functionality with R, preferably something that worked well with Mac-Vim. Is there something that will display a function's arguments on the bottom of the screen (or in a mouse-over) when I begin typing an R function in (Mac)VIM?

Comment: There have been some discussions on the R-SIG-Mac mailing list about how that actually happns. I seem to remember that there is an R function authored by Deepayan Sarkar (of lattice fame) that does the look-up and displays the list of formals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2628

If you want to use the R function that the MacGUI uses for completion try `?rcompgen`.

Comment: I use vim-r as my go-to plugin for R in Vim. It's a very slick plugin. It'll display a function's args if you do \ra. It's the best I have with vim right now, but I was hoping for something automatic. Sorry for being a spoiled brat ;).